# k6: WARpanic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, k6

I'm trying to run a Performance TEst with a tool named K6 (free and open-source load testing tool), my test is about to test a Website Performance, and when I run the Test I got this:

```
WARN[0029] Request Failed                     
error="Get https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xtee7r5-ztY/hqdefault.jpg?
sqp=-oaymwEYCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDCwgBFQAAiEIYAXAB&rs=AOn4CLBlViQFOGYBjH0iGMUyeyWwj0CRHQ: 
read tcp 10.61.19.91:27672->172.217.19.86:443: wsarecv: A connection attempt failed because 
the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."
WARpanic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x30 pc=0xa48c2c]
```

The test can be run on the command line with command:

k6 run --out influxdb=http://localhost:8086/VideoRecord_DB D:\Applications\K6-Scripts\VideoRecording.js`

this is the k6 version:

```
C:\Users\diz>k6 version
```

k6 v0.26.1 (dev build, go1.13, windows/amd64)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because of an issue we had with the k6 v0.26.1 builds for Windows. Because of a CI mistake, we built that specific k6 version with an old Go version that had a bug.

We released k6 v0.26.2 specifically to address that: https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/releases/tag/v0.26.2

Please try v0.26.2 and if the problem persists, open a new GitHub issue: https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/new?labels=bug&template=bug_report.md

Comment: I downloaded the v0.26.2, and I run my script, and norw I got another error which is:    ```WARN[0063] Request Failed error="read tcp 10.61.19.91:35274->89.27.131.208:443: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." ```

Comment: This is a not a k6 problem anymore - the server you're testing has closed the connection.